# Android - onCreate() called despite using SingleTop launch mode

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I currently have two activities in my application.

The second activity in the application prompts a notification icon to be presented in the notification bar.

The intent from the first activity to the second uses the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLETOP` and the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flags in the intent. The same goes for the intent used in the `PendingIntent` from the notification.

My aim is that the second activity is only a single activity and only created once, then when the user leaves via the home button and then goes back to the activity via the notification, the instance that was running comes back and `onCreate` is NOT called.

This approach works on almost all devices, however testing on one device in particular (A Sony Xperia device - 4.0.4) has shown that it doesn't work in all cases.

On the Sony Xperia the `onCreate` of the second Activity is always called when it is entered into by the user, even from the notification.

I have tried using singleTop in the `Manifest` as well without success. Is this a bug in the device or am I doing something wrong? Perhaps missing a flag I need or something along those lines?

If anyone wants more specific code or information please let me know and I will post it.

Comment: Are you sure the old activity still exists?  While imperfectly correlated, try looking at the process ID in logcat - if that has changed, it's unavoidable that a new activity must be created.  You can also try logging your onDestroy(), but that's not guaranteed to happen in situations of sufficiently dire memory pressure.

Comment: Indeed I am aware of that and have checked, my apologies for not posting that, the activity is still alive, onDestroy is has not been called in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that it is up to Android to kill your Activity when your app is backgrounded. So there is no guarantee that your activity will stay alive while your app is backgrounded.
In any case, in my projects I end up using `singleInstance` launch mode for activities that only one instance should be running at the same time.

Just try to update your `AndroidManifest` with `singleInstance` launch mode for this activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.your.package.YourActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for the reply, I am aware of that and have checked, in my case the Acitvity is still alive and has not been killed by the Android OS. I have also tired singleInstance which gives me the same behaviour on the Sony Xperia device.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you try to set launch mode in `Manifest` and call your activity w/o any parameters? When you launch Activity from the code and set `singleTop` f.i, it usually overrides launch mode set in Manifest

Comment: yes I have checked and re-checked! It looks like its a bug on the device itself as it doesn't behave as expected in any scenario.